# Distributed lock in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration-distributed-lock

I have 2 instances of containers with scheduled task and I would like to protect against start the same task in every docker container. I decided to make distributed lock using SQL Server.

I added configuration

```
  @Bean
    public DefaultLockRepository DefaultLockRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultLockRepository(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcLockRegistry jdbcLockRegistry(LockRepository lockRepository) {
        return new JdbcLockRegistry(lockRepository);
    }
```

And I'm trying acquire the lock like this:

```
   public void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        boolean lockAcquired;
        var lock = lockRegistry.obtain("main");

        try {
            
            lockAcquired = lock.tryLock();
            if (lockAcquired == true) {
                logger.info("Locked");
            } else {
                logger.info("Not locked");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            lockAcquired = false;
            logger.info("Not locked");
        }

        Thread.sleep(3600000);

        lock.unlock();
    }
```

I started 2 instances of application with identical code.
When I entered to method of first instance of application, lock has been acquired - and I've got "Locked" message - so it's ok

In database I saw the entry like this:

```
LOCK_KEY    REGION  CLIENT_ID   CREATED_DATE
fad58de7-3664-35db-8650-cfefac2fcd61    DEFAULT c0314b87-0bee-4bdd-8567-a939fd21f0bf    2024-03-16 13:20:43.2559575I saw that in datatabase I've got new entry like this:
```

When I started second instance of application I expected to get message "Not locked", because lock has been acquired in first app which still running, but not - I've got log "Locked" again and my database entry has been updated to:

```
LOCK_KEY    REGION  CLIENT_ID   CREATED_DATE
fad58de7-3664-35db-8650-cfefac2fcd61    DEFAULT ad58971d-c991-4709-a03b-9acb39a38c54    2024-03-16 13:24:42.3002365
```

So my distributed lock doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I protect against execute scheduled task using distributed lock in many docker containers.

//UPDATE

When I execute method in two instances in short time between (like less then 5 s) it works, but when I execute method in first instance and I'm trying execute it in second instance after 30s it doesn't work.

//UPDATE2

As Alex sugested it was a problem with TTL in DefaultLockRepository.
The lock was set to default time 10 seconds.
After chaning code like this:

```
 @Bean
    public DefaultLockRepository DefaultLockRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
        var repo = new DefaultLockRepository(dataSource);
        repo.setTimeToLive(1000 * 100);
        return repo;
    }
```

The lock is set to 100s and during the next 100s other service instance cannot lock the method.

Comment: kindly check whether the lock.tryLock() tries to return true in both instances

Comment: You need to check what `tryLock` returns. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock()

Comment: I've chcecked and I always gets true - I updated my example in post.
Anyway - when I execute method in second instance in very short time (less 5s) lock works - so propably I's a problem with lock time.

Comment: @santal when you say it doesn't work using a longer time gap, what is happening? Also your example never releases the lock?

Comment: I think you should change `TTL` in `DefaultLockRepository`  using `setTimeToLive` method, cause its default value is 10 seconds

Comment: @Alex yes - this is a solution! After changing TTL in DefaultLockRepository it works!
Can You please post Your comment as an answer to question?

Comment: If it's a deadlock issue this suggests your application logic maybe the cause of the problem

Comment: I won't post it as answer because it's not a good idea to use `spring lock support` for your case. If you just need to prevent service duplicates it's enough to use own shared `lock` in db checking it's presence. I have answered why your code doesn't work in time cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ShedLock successfully. Adding following to the pom.xml (or corresponding gradle)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${shedlock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then add the following to the main class or a configuration class (example in Kotlin but same concept for Java):

```
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "10m")
class MainClass //...

    @Bean
    fun lockProvider(dataSource: DataSource): LockProvider {
        return JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource)
    }
//...
```

Then add the following annotation to the method:

```
@Service
class NeedingLockService //...

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000) // using it at a schedule interval in my case but not relevant for lock
@SchedulerLock(name = "nameOfTheLock")
fun dispatch() { // name doesn't matter
//...
}
```

In this kotlin example, the service will run every 5 second but only in one of the container/pod if you have multiple.

Notes:

1. There is no guaranties that it will run on a specific container/pod even though it usually does.
2. The datasource obviously needs to be the same in all instances for it to work
3. You need to create the needed table. Here is a liquibase file for it:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 5
      author: Geoffrey
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: shedlock
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: name
                  type: varchar(64)
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: lock_until
                  type: timestamp
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: locked_at
                  type: timestamp
                  defaultValueComputed: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: locked_by
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
```